# In ASP.NET how do I find the Control ID of a TextBox that is nested within a DetailsView which is then nested in an AJAX UpdatePanel control?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, detailsview

n ASP.NET how do I find the Control ID of a TextBox that is nested within a DetailsView which is then nested in an AJAX UpdatePanel control ?

The heirachy is: UpdatePanel1 -> dvContentDetail (DetailsView Control) -> TextBox2

I have tried something like the following but just says that the object isn't found:

```
UpdatePanel1.FindControl("dvContentDetail").FindControl("TextBox2").ClientID
```

Comment: can u plz tell me where u finding control...
can u post ur page code...

Comment: I think what you are trying is getting control is not in correct place... I think you have to get control in detailsView databound event, If you want to get control and set some values....

Comment: Yes, I am getting a better result if I try to find the control after it has been databound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to find control from updatepanel, because these controls directly available, so you code will be like this...

```
TextBox TextBox2 = (TextBox)dvContentDetail.FindControl("TextBox2");
```

Comment: This didn't work - just got the same error message saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: This did work once I had put the code in the right place ! - ie. after the control had been databound. - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the code below.  But if you know the Hierarchy is *not* going to change it would be better to do a series of "FindControl" calls.  To discover the correct hierarchy, Debug the app and search through the Control Hierarchy.

```
public static T FindControlRecursiveInternal<T>(Control startingControl, string controlToFindID) where T : Control
{
    if (startingControl == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(controlToFindID))
        return (T)null;

    Control foundControl = startingControl.FindControl(controlToFindID);
    if (foundControl == null)
    {
        foreach (Control innerControl in startingControl.Controls)
        {
            foundControl = FindControlRecursiveInternal<T>(innerControl, controlToFindID);
            if (foundControl != null)
                break;
        }
    }

    return (T)foundControl;
}
```